# Issue in activityIndicatorView to show in UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Using activityIndicatorView to show front of the `UITableViewController`, but it show inside the `UITableViewController`, How to fix this?

I tried this:

```
activityView = [[activityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 130, 200, 100)];
    [self showActivity];

-(void) showActivity
{
   
    [self.tableView addSubview:activityView];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it in view as a subview instead of `UITableView` and set as a superview so its display front of view like bellow:

```
[self.view addSubview:activityView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityView];
```